# What does the sentence "It won't be until later on in the week given a last minute work trip" mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning, expressions

In reply to an inquiry someone wrote:

> You will get an answer, but it probably won't be until ***later on in the
>   week given a last minute work trip***.

What does the sentence mean? And what is the simplified version of the phrase: *later on in the week given a last minute work trip*?

Answer (score 1):

The person is stating you will get a reply but because of a work trip (arranged at the "last minute") they are not able to reply until later in the week.

They are assuming you understand the implicit context in "given". They have been called away unexpectedly, for the work trip, so it is a "given" that they cannot reply until they return.